# Please, help me to implement subset function

Tags: arrays, scala

I tried to copy it to array, but I can't accept two (Sets) parameters

```
def subset(a:Set[Int],b:Set[Int]):Boolean={
    var x = new Array[Int](a.size)
    var y = new Array[Int](b.size) 
  }
```

or can you explain how to recieve two arrays as parameter?

```
def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val a =  Set(2,3,4,5,6)
    val b = Set(2,3,4,5)
    var x = new Array[Int](a.size)
    var y = new Array[Int](b.size)
```

i wish to put x and y to function subset and do same but not by Set

Comment: I have no idea what is your question. Please try to improve the English in it.

Comment: Additionally, `Array` is rarely justified and really cannot be of much, if any, help in writing a subset algorithm. Lastly, the standard library `Set` already defines `subsetOf` to test whether the subset relation holds between two `Set`s.

Answer (score 0):

You can transform `Set` to `Array` or `Array` to `Set`:

```
scala> val array = Array(1, 3, 5)
array: Array[Int] = Array(1, 3, 5)

scala> array.toSet
res0: scala.collection.immutable.Set[Int] = Set(1, 3, 5)

scala> val set = Set(7, 3, 8)
set: scala.collection.immutable.Set[Int] = Set(7, 3, 8)

scala> set.toArray
res1: Array[Int] = Array(7, 3, 8)
```

If you want a program to take a collection of `Int`s as a command-line argument, you'll have to parse a string:

```
object Test extends App {
  val x: Array[Int] = args(0).split(",").map{ _.toInt }
  val y: Array[Int] = args(1).split(",").map{ _.toInt }
  println("x: " + x.mkString("Array(", ", ", ")"))
  println("y: " + y.mkString("Array(", ", ", ")"))
}
```

Usage:

```
>scala Test "1,2,3" "10,0,-5"
x: Array(1, 2, 3)
y: Array(10, 0, -5)
```